# PHP can't display Chinese character

Tags: php, apache, nginx, phalcon, chinese-locale

I just migrated my codebase to a new server. Previously, the user saves Chinese characters to the MariaDB database. In the database it saves as below:

[image]

This is the text when I copy the content from database: å¹¿å·žå‡Œè¿è´§è¿ä»£ç†æœåŠ¡æœ‰é™å…¬å

My old server using Ubuntu, PHP 5.5.9-1 & Apache, it shows the character correctly in frontend:

[image]

In the new server, I am using Centos, PHP 7.2.27 with Apache & Nginx it shows:

[image]

I have tried many things but still cannot fix. I am not sure if it PHP issue or server issue. Anyone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Check your encoding in database. And also encoding connection to database.

Comment: Database encoding is UTF-8. The weird thing is my old server using PHP5 can show the character correctly while the new server using PHP 7 showing the weird character. Both servers connect & read same database.

Answer (score 0):

uses utf-8 charset, include below lines at top of php page

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```